# Jenkins Jobs Windows powershell script $lastexitcode not failing the jenkins job

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins

```
if (Test-Path "c:\Temp\some.msi")
{
    start-process  -Wait -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList -somearguments
}   
else        
{
    Write-Host "MSI does not exist at the specified location....c:\Temp\"
    exit 1
}

$lastexitcode
```

1. the .msi is not present in the specified path it goes to else and print what is in else.
2. now i have added the code EXIT 1 and the value of  $lastexitcode will be 1. but still  jenkins windows powershell job shows finished: success.

Can someone please point me what i'm doing wrong. i want the mark the jenkins job failed. I'm new to jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `;` before the exit.

```
if (Test-Path "c:\Temp\some.msi") { start-process -Wait -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList -somearguments}
else { Write-Host "MSI does not exist at the specified location....c:\Temp\"; Exit 1 }
```

So the PowerShell plugin in Jenkins is pretty retarded, you have to force the exit code on it, so it would understand errors. What I found to work for me is:

```
if ($error) { $error; exit 1 }
```

The `$error` is a variable that is populated by PowerShell engine with the errors that are occurring during execution. So if it exists > there were errors > we need to fail the build. Of course it won't work with try\catch blocks. But just as an alternative.